# How rf remotes for "cloning" rolling code find matching codes?

Tags: cryptography, brute-force, key-exchange

I've been tinkering with a rf (garage door) remote control that has a scanner mode (google JMA SR-48 for details).
This mode works for Mutancode and Erreka which I assume would be similar to KeeLoq.

Basically, it reads original remote twice, then it indicates to set it in the scanner mode. 
It loops through codes and once finds the match (garage door opens) it is indicated to press back button which stops scanning.

Would it mean that the remote control has already contains Mutancode and Erreka algorithms and is basically brute forcing serial number and rolling code?

Comment: I've got two of these, and also managed to use it with V2 rolling codes. I was expecting the original remote to get out of sync and stop working after a while using the copy, but no, both the original and the copy still work perfectly. No idea how they manage that.